# Overriding a gems methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, overriding

I am currently using the Feedzirra gem to import RSS feeds into my web app, but I need to override a few methods to meet my needs.
I know how to override the methods, but I'm unsure where I should do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Quite common way is to add `feedzirra.rb` file into your `config/initializers/` dir.

Answer (score 1):

How about `require "feedzirra"` at the beginning of the file where you want to override the methods? By using that, you are sure that it is loaded. You should then create a file `feedzirra_adds.rb` in `config/initializers` as said by @fl00r, and do the changing definitions there.

```
file: config/initializers/feedzirra_adds.rb
require "feedzirra"
...
```